# Question based on Algorithmic Complexity?

Tags: discussion

Can a question on this site have a winner based on the lowest complexity? Each answer would require the code's complexity in Big-O notation, and the winner would be the first to submit an answer with the lowest (so, if three people submit answers with `O(n)`, the first one wins).

I can't remember seeing any questions like this, so I am curious as to what the decision will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This already exists, as the [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) tag. From its wiki excerpt:

> Fastest-algorithm competitions are won by the answer with the smallest asymptotic time complexity. For challenges based on actual runtime, use [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) instead.

Comment: I never noticed that before. Thanks before the reference!